# Padrão de organização de projeto WEB (HTML, CSS, PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

Eu não sei exatamente como organizar o meu projeto, eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
/produtos/
  cabecalho.php
  index.php
  rodape.php
```

dentro do cabeçalho e do rodapé tem um

```
if(verificacao != 1){sai da pagina}
```

e o meu *index* define a variável `$verificacao = 1`; para que as páginas só possam ser exibidas a partir do `index.php`

Eu sei que isso é uma gambiarra, mas foi uma forma que eu encontrei de organizar meu código e eu gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão de projeto, algum documentação para isso, uma orientação, algo assim.

Obs: Criar `produtos.php` e colocar tudo junto é inviável por que o código fica uma bagunça imensa (mesmo tendo um arquivo separado para o CSS e o JS).

Comment: Ok, qual é exatamente o problema que você pretende resolver? Organização de pastas ou bloquear alguns arquivos de serem acessados diretamente?

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma ajuda na parte de organização.

Comment: A resposta para isso será baseado em opinião, como previsto na [help] (se não viu, recomendo acessá-la e fazer o [tour]). Não existe regras sobre como você irá organizar o seu projeto. Somente você, como responsável, que pode determinar com base naquilo que facilita a sua vida.

Comment: Realmente eu sou quem decide, porém, eu gostaria de um auxilio, de alguem mais experiente que ja bateu nessa tecla e encontrou alguma luz que o ajudou kk.

Comment: Exemplos de organização, de seus próprios projetos ou de algum no qual você se baseia. A minha ideia aqui não é copiar/imitar, mas sim a de analisar e criar um "estilo" próprio a partir de coisas que funcionam e são realmente viáveis.

Comment: Se quer um rumo, busque por HTML boilerplate e estude tudo, mas tudo mesmo, dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns gostam de impor um padrão, mais você não precisa segui-los, tão pouco deve acreditar na frase "não reinvente a roda".

A vantagem de seguir o padrão é que você saberá resolver um problema de forma mais rápida e pratica, além de poder contar com a ajuda de outros desenvolvedores, sem que seja necessário mostrar o seu código, pois você estará de acordo com a documentação da linguagem, do framework ou mesmo do CMS, então poderá entender e usar os exemplos que existirem lá (na documentação), além disso, se você estiver fazendo um projeto para um cliente, seguir o padrão, facilitará para o próximo desenvolvedor modificar o código, embora alguns sabotem para o cliente retornar a quem "resolve". Você não falou se esta fazendo no código puro ou em um framework, mais no php puro, você pode fazer assim:

```
/Assets 

   - css
   - img
   - js
   - vendor

/Int ou config

 - config.php
 - db.php
 - functions.php
 - route.php

// Aqui você coloca todos os arquivos de configuração

/Public

- index.php
- .htaccess
- manifest.json (opcional)
- sw.js (opcional)
- favicon.ico

/View
   - /layout
      - header
         - head.php
      - footer
         - footer.php
      - page.php // layout da pagina  

  - /page(s)
    // suas paginas aqui
```

Basicamente é isso, porem, é mais fácil você usar o laravel se estiver sem tempo, pois, ele já tem ali tudo configurado.

- os nomes dos arquivos não precisão ser em inglês, desconfie de quem diga isso.
- no caso do route.php, você pode criar uma pasta ao invés de um arquivo, por exemplo

  /router

  - api.php
  - rotas.php
- eu prefiro substituir /header e /footer por /global e colocar tudo lá, mais você quem decide.
- no caso da pasta Public, quando for passar para o servidor, pode colocar os arquivos na raiz do projeto, ela não é necessária.

- /assets
- /config
- /router (opcional)
- /view
- index.php
- .htaccess
- manifest.json (opcional)
- sw.js (opcional)
- favicon.ico

- você pode colocar todas as paginas na pasta view/pages, inclusive a home, e usar o arquivo index.php, apenas para carregar bibliotecas, como é feito no laravel.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta cara, era exatamente isso que eu queria, um norte para eu poder me basear e organizar meu projeto.

Comment: de nada, precisando volte a postar : )

Answer (score 8):

Primeiro, não tem uma forma 100% certa de padronizar um projeto, o que tem por aí são alguns padrões preestabelecidos pela comunidade, que diz ser o melhor ou o a mais aceito, até aparecer alguma falha 'nesse padrão' (seja de segurança, usabilidade, performance, etc.).

O que eu sugiro, no entanto, é aprender os pontos fundamentais da linguagem em si que você escolheu usar como ferramenta de trabalho ou por *hobby* mesmo. Em seguida, aprender algum padrão desses já usados, como por exemplo o padrão *MVC (Model-View-Controller)*, que, para mim, é muito complicado para um iniciante aprendê-lo.
Veja bem: até o Mozilla Firefox, em seu site de desenvolvimento, diz que não há um padrão.
O Facebook, por meio do seu Framework React JS, diz a mesma coisa.

Se você pegar 100 projetos de 100 empresas diferentes, verás que, numa probabilidade de quase 100% delas, os projetos serem diferentes, e, em alguns, não estarem em nenhum desses padrões preestabelecidos.

Novamente, para concluir, corroboro dizendo que o mais importante é aprender os fundamentos, isto é, aprender o que a sua linguagem de programação faz, suas principais características, etc, então, depois que tiver, ao menos, um certo domínio da mesma, escolher um padrão desse.  Pode ser até o MVC, mas com o advento da programação funcional, como por exemplo, em React Js (front-end), seria legal aprender as duas formas.

Além disso, veja a diferença entre programação **monolítica**, que, em resumo, é colocar tudo em um único lugar e programação baseada em **serviços ou em micro-serviços**, que as partes do seu projeto são colocadas em lugares diferentes. Atualmente, esse último está sendo bastante aceito.

> Quando você disse: *"o código fica uma bagunça imensa"*, você, provavelmente, referiu-se à programação **monolítica** (mesmo sem saber), embora na programação baseada em serviços, também haja bagunça.

No momento em que você aprender realmente os fundamentos da programação web, qualquer coisa que você colocar pra aprender, aprenderá facilmente, até mesmo qualquer padrão desse.

Então, comece com uma estrutura básica mesmo (pode ser a monolítica), você mesmo pode criar; entenda como se importa os arquivos, caminhos relativos, absolutos, por exemplo:
a diferença `include, include_once, require, require_once`, etc., em php.

```html
root:
    - index.php (caso seja php)
    - assets (onde irão os arquivos css, javascripts, fontes)
    - class (pode colocar algumas classes php)
```

Eu, particularmente, não aconselho usar um padrão desse (*MVC*, etc.) no início, porque você não vai absorver muita coisa, podendo até atrapalhar a aprendizagem no início.

**REFERÊNCIA:**

1. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript
3. https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Ja havia tentado o padrão MVC, mas é muito complicado ainda kk, eu sabia que existia algum outro padrão de projeto, mas não sabia que se chamava monolítica, você ja me deu um norte bem bacana, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, eu vou pesquisar sobre o conteúdo que você me indicou.